# JSF 2 exception: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: xml, jsf-2, character-encoding

I'm working on a web app using JSF 2 and Tomcat 6. I am getting the following exception: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence` when I try to load the page in question. I have accented Spanish characters in the display text, and I've figured out that they are causing the exception. For example, `<p>ñ</p>` causes an error, but `<p>n</p>` works fine. Note that this example text is hard coded and wrapped in a `<ui:define>` tag.

I'll also note that in the client .xhtml file (the page in question) uses a template. The template file has the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` declaration. Any suggestions on what could be the problem? I've searched the internet and SO, and there are a lot of questions out there concerning this specific exception, but most don't deal with JSF, but involve other details that influence what might be the cause of the problem. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you change the encoding to "ISO-8859-1" from "UTF-8"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...I tried "ISO-8859-1" and got the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You cannot have tried ISO-8859-1 and gotten the same error. Because the error is about UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, I did, and it gave me an exception mentioning UTF-8. Also, when I check the source, regardless of which encoding I use in the template, the HTML head shows charset=ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Just checking the exact exception with ISO-8859-1, it is slightly different than the one I initially included in my question: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.` You see, it says "2 of 4-byte" instead of "2 of 3-byte". However, I'm not sure what that is telling me...from the initial error to now I reduced the text to just the one character. Maybe I'll recompare the exceptions using the exact same text.

Comment: Ok, just rechecked using UTF-8, with only the 'ñ' character. It gives the EXACT same exception as when using ISO-8859-1, including the "2 of 4-byte" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further investigation (trial and error), I got it to work by changing a setting in Eclipse. I didn't mention in the question that I was using Eclipse, out of ignorance of the issue I guess...hindsight. Anyway, here's what I did that made my page display the text with Spanish accented characters: in Eclipse, under `Preferences/General/Workspace`, there is an option for "Text file encoding" that was set to the default of "Cp1252". I changed this to use UTF-8, and it worked. I also changed an "Encoding" setting to use UTF-8 under each of the folowing: `Preferences/Web/CSS Files`, `Preferences/Web/HTML Files`, and `Preferences/XML/XML Files`. I had changed those (without successfully displaying the accented characters) before finally finding the "General/Workspace" setting, so I'm not sure whether they had an impact or not.